# register new xmpp account with node-xmpp ( node.js )

Tags: node.js, xmpp, ejabberd, node-xmpp

I'm looking at '[XEP-0077 in-band registration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html)' about how to register a new XMPP account.  Here is my code.  I use node-xmpp to connect my node.js application to an ejabberd  server.

```
var net = require('net');
var xmpp = require('node-xmpp');
var cache = new Object();

net.createServer( function(socket) {
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.addListener('data',function(data) {
   data = data.substr(0,data.length-2);

    if(cache.admin==undefined && data=='login') {
        var ejabberd =new xmpp.Client({jid:"admin@mine",password:'12345',host:'192.168.7.202',port:'5222'});
        cache.admin = ejabberd;

        cache.admin.addListener('online',function() {
            cache.admin.send(new xmpp.Element('presence',{type:'chat'}).c('show').c('status').t('mine status'));
            cache.admin.send(new xmpp.Element('iq',{type:'get',id:'reg1'}).c('query',{xmlns:'jabber:iq:register'}));            
        })

        cache.admin.addListener('stanza',function(stanza) {
            if(stanza.is('iq')) {
                console.log(stanza.children[1]);
            }
        })

        cache.admin.addListener('end',function() {
            cache.admin.end();
            cache.admin = undefined;
        })

    }

    if(cache.admin!=undefined && data=='logout') {
        cache.admin.end();
        cache.admin = undefined;
    } else if(cache.admin!=undefined && data=='register') {
        cache.admin.send(new xmpp.Element('iq',{type:'set',id:'reg1'}).c('query',{xmlns:'jabber:iq:register'}).c('username').t('alow').up().c('password').t('test'));
    }
});

}).listen(5000);
```

If i run this code, I get this error:

```
{ name: 'error',
    parent: 
     { name: 'iq',
     parent: null,
     attrs: 
      { from: 'admin@mine',
        to: 'admin@mine/20108892991316770090454637',
        id: 'reg1',
        type: 'error',
        xmlns: 'jabber:client',
        'xmlns:stream': 'http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' },
     children: [ [Object], [Circular] ] },
    attrs: { code: '403', type: 'auth' },
    children: 
    [ { name: '**forbidden**',
       parent: [Circular],
       attrs: [Object],
       children: [] } ] }
```

In 'XEP-0077: In-Band Registration' it says that the `forbidden` reason means that "The sender does not have sufficient permissions to cancel the registration".

How can I get such permissions?

Comment: Could you post the `mod_register` section of your ejabberd configuration file?

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Did you solved this?

Answer (score 4):

I have been strugling with something similar, I wanted to register a new user account via in-band registraton from nodejs to an ejabberd server running in ubuntu. Here is what I did and worked for me:

```
//Dependencies
var xmpp = require('node-xmpp');

//Host configuration
var host = "localhost";
var port = "5222";
var admin = "sebastian@localhost";
var adminPass = "adminPass";

var connection = new xmpp.Client({
    jid: admin,
    password: adminPass,
    host: host,
    port: port
});

//user to be registered name & pass
var newUserName = "pepe";
var newUserPass = "pepePass";

//Stream
var iq = "<stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:component:accept' to='localhost'><iq type='set' id='reg2'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'><username>" + newUserName + "</username><password>" + newUserPass + "</password></query></iq></stream>";

//Send
connection.send(iq);

//End
connection.end();
```

The var iq is kind of messy, I suppose that if you know how to use Strophe.js in a propper way that part could look a little bit nicer and cleaner. I was missing the  section of the xml, it seems that if you want to send a stream, you have to provide a valid ejabberd namespace, that was what was failing for me. Hope this helps you sort your problem out.

Comment: hi @taxicala are you done above one beacuse now i am doing same process  could you please explain that

Answer (score 1):

Which server are you using?  Are you sure it has XEP-77 enabled?  Test with an existing client.  Ensure that the account you're trying to create does not already exist.  Ensure that the account has the correct domain name.

Comment: what do you mean by which server...? i donwload ejabberd from http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads..

how to enable XEP-77...?

i already test with pidgin, i can add account with pidgin...
but i can't run my code...